# Oracle XML extract path

Tags: xml, oracle, extract

I have been trying to extract data from xml using oracle.
This is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xfa generator="XFA2_4" APIVersion="3.6.12227.0"?>
<xdp:xdp xmlns:xdp="http://ns.adobe.com/xdp/">
   <config xmlns="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xci/1.0/">
      </agent name="designer">
         <destination>pdf</destination>
         <pdf>
            <fontInfo />
         </pdf>
      </agent>
      <present>
         <pdf>
            <version>1.65</version>
```

I want to extract info about version.

```
Select XMLTYPE (blob_to_clob(datoteka)).extract('//xdp:xdp/config/present/pdf/version/text()','xmlns:xdp="http://ns.adobe.com/xdp/"').getstringval() AS Verzija from datoteka
```

I get null as a result. I'm guessing path is creating the problem because when I use just "//text()" as path i get data in result. 
I need help on how to fix this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<config xmlns="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xci/1.0/">` Here is problem. Defult name space is changed to `http://www.xfa.org/schema/xci/1.0/"` 
Extract has to be change to.

```
extract('//xdp:xdp/config/present/pdf/version/text()','xmlns="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xci/1.0/" xmlns:xdp="http://ns.adobe.com/xdp/"')
```

Comment: This was very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You also have an error in the XML you posted ( `</agent name="designer">`).

Here is a working code

```
Select XMLTYPE('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xfa generator="XFA2_4" APIVersion="3.6.12227.0"?>
<xdp:xdp xmlns:xdp="http://ns.adobe.com/xdp/">
  <config xmlns="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xci/1.0/">
    <agent name="designer">
      <destination>pdf</destination>
      <pdf>
        <fontInfo />
      </pdf>
    </agent>
    <present>
      <pdf>
        <version>1.65</version>
      </pdf>
    </present>
  </config>
</xdp:xdp>').extract('//xdp:xdp/config/present/pdf/version/text()','xmlns="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xci/1.0/" xmlns:xdp="http://ns.adobe.com/xdp/"')
       .getstringval() AS Verzija
  from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Arkadiusz already mentioned you need to include the default namespace as well as `xdp`:

```
select XMLType(blob_to_clob(datoteka)).extract('/xdp:xdp/config/present/pdf/version/text()',
    'xmlns:xdp="http://ns.adobe.com/xdp/" xmlns="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xci/1.0/').getstringval()
    as verzija
from datoteka;

VERZIJA   
----------
1.65
```

(Run against modified XML; fixed the opening agent tag, and added missing closing tags).

You can also use an XMLQuery instead of extract:

```
select XMLQuery('declare namespace xdp="http://ns.adobe.com/xdp/";  (: :)
    declare default element namespace "http://www.xfa.org/schema/xci/1.0/";  (: :)
    /xdp:xdp/config/present/pdf/version/text()'
  passing XMLType(blob_to_clob(datoteka))
  returning content) as verzija
from datoteka;

VERZIJA   
----------
1.65
```

If your XML document might have multiple versions you can use XMLTable to retrieve them all:

```
select x.verzija
from datoteka d
cross join xmltable(xmlnamespaces('http://ns.adobe.com/xdp/' as "xdp",
    default 'http://www.xfa.org/schema/xci/1.0/'),
  '/xdp:xdp/config/present/pdf'
  passing XMLType(blob_to_clob(datoteka))
  columns verzija path 'version'
) x;

VERZIJA   
----------
1.65
```